# A general solution for this type of matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, semidefinite-programming

I want to know whether there is a general solution to this problem. I want to solve the following matrix equation with respect to $X$.

$$ \mathbf{X}^{-1}-\mathbf{A}- \mathbf{X}\odot \mathbf{D} = \mathbf{0}$$

where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product, $\mathbf{D}$ is lower-triangular matrix and every other matrix is symmetric positive definite. Would there be a solution for this?